# Ember.js with Ember.testing = true

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to get testing working in Ember.js with the Ember.testing = true flag set to disable the automatic run loop etc

I have this code

```
Ember.testing = true;

Ember.run(function() {  
  App = Ember.Application.create();
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("home", { path: "/" });
});


Ember.run(function() {
  App.initialize();
});
```

And i get thuis error already

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an Ember.run
```

I know you need to run async code within a Ember.run which i have as per any examples i can find!!

Can anyone show me what i am doing wrong or even get the jsin example to not show this error ?

See jsbin here http://jsbin.com/uxalap/14/edit

UPDATED:

I am using Konacha to run my tests and when i use the latest RC1 i get an error when wrapping the Ember.Application.create() and App.initialize() in Em.run.    When i remove these i get no errors.    Is this correct now in latest master ?

Thanks 
Rick

Comment: Put your `App.Router.map` call in a run-block.

Comment: @Waleed Khan thanks but when i do that in the jsbin i still get the same error.   don't you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ember.testing` was changed since RC1, if you want to use it you should use master

[Here's an updated working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uxalap/17/edit)